# How to share a folder between KVM host and guest using virt-manager?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, shared-folders, virt-manager

For some time now, I've been using `virt-manager` to manage my virtual machines. When I want to copy a file from the host to the vm, I have been using `scp` to copy via `ssh` over the network. This is kind of tedious, and there must be a way to share a folder similar to VirtualBox. So how can I best share a folder between a KVM host and guest using virt-manager?

Answer (score 8):

You could use 9p sharing as described at http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/9p_virtio .

Other possibilities include usage of a network file system like NFS or CIFS/Samba.

Comment: Unfortunately the instructions you linked to don't work in Ubuntu 14.04. Ubuntu doesn't recognize the 9p filesystem with the mount command and needs the 9mount command which I still have not got to work.

Comment: @flob There is no `/usr/bin/qemu-kvm`. What to do ?

Comment: @Kat Amsterdam did you solve that ?

Answer (score 1):

**9p just works on QEMU KVM Ubuntu 18.04 guest/host**

I'm not sure why it wasn't working before, but now it just works. I basically just add to the QEMU CLI:

```
-virtfs local,path=/path/to/share,mount_tag=host0,security_model=mapped,id=host0
```

and mount on guest as:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/9p
mount -t 9p -o trans=virtio,version=9p2000.L host0 /mnt/9p
```

Exact setup described at: [How to run Ubuntu desktop on QEMU?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/884534/how-to-run-ubuntu-desktop-on-qemu/1046792#1046792)