# KVM: Copy (drag and drop) files between Ubuntu host to Windows 7 guest

Tags: 16.04, kvm-virtualization, copy, drag-and-drop

I am not sure why there is so little clear information in the net about the issue:

I just want to copy (drag and drop) files between the Ubuntu 16.04 host and the Windows 7 client.

I expected this as a basic feature. But it does not work.

Comment: This is not a 'basic feature', and I don't know what hypervisors provide that. When using KVM with `spice`and `QXL`and have the drivers and vd-agent installed, you are able to copy/paste the clipboard and to have shared folders (see  https://www.spice-space.org/features.html)

Comment: VMware and Hyper-V support it. I can copy text between host and guest. But not files :/

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/290668/how-to-share-a-folder-between-kvm-host-and-guest-using-virt-manager

Comment: This is in fact possible with "Gnome Boxes", it offers drag and drop functionality with files. KVM unfortunately, does not.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. I think it will also work for you.

1. Download and install spice tool ([`spice-guest-tools-latest.exe`](https://www.spice-space.org/download/windows/spice-guest-tools/spice-guest-tools-latest.exe)) on your guest OS (Windows 7/8/10).
2. Restart or shut down your guest OS (Windows 7/8/10).

Comment: Really? I'm sure you can share clipboard but not files (drag-and-drop)

Comment: do i add the file onto device i want to d&d (drag and drop) to, like a raspberry pi and will this work with clipboard too?

Answer (score 1):

## Work around #1

**Create a samba share on the host.**

Since client and host should be able to communicate via a virtual network interface - automatically - this is a very easy workaround.

Comment: This is NOT trivial at all and a very complicated way to do this. Compare this with drag and drop.